# How do I treat an integer as an array of bytes in Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to decode the result of the Python os.wait() function. This returns, according to the Python docs:

> a tuple containing its pid and exit status indication: a 16-bit number, whose low byte is the signal number that killed the process, and whose high byte is the exit status (if the signal number is zero); the high bit of the low byte is set if a core file was produced.

How do I decode the exit status indication (which is an integer) to obtain the high and low byte? To be specific, how do I implement the decode function used in the following code snippet:

```
(pid,status) = os.wait()
(exitstatus, signum) = decode(status)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This will do what you want:

```
signum = status & 0xff
exitstatus = (status & 0xff00) >> 8
```

Comment: Although the `& 0xff00` is redundant if `status` really is only 16 bits.

Answer (score 13):

To answer your general question, you can use [bit manipulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_manipulation)

```
pid, status = os.wait()
exitstatus, signum = status & 0xFF, (status & 0xFF00) >> 8
```

However, there are also [built-in functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) for interpreting exit status values:

```
pid, status = os.wait()
exitstatus, signum = os.WEXITSTATUS( status ), os.WTERMSIG( status )
```

See also:

- os.WCOREDUMP()
- os.WIFCONTINUED()
- os.WIFSTOPPED()
- os.WIFSIGNALED()
- os.WIFEXITED()
- os.WSTOPSIG()

Answer (score 2):

You can get break your int into a string of unsigned bytes with the [struct](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) module:

```
import struct
i = 3235830701  # 0xC0DEDBAD
s = struct.pack(">L", i)  # ">" = Big-endian, "<" = Little-endian
print s         # '\xc0\xde\xdb\xad'
print s[0]      # '\xc0'
print ord(s[0]) # 192 (which is 0xC0)
```

If you couple this with the [array](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html) module you can do this more conveniently:

```
import struct
i = 3235830701  # 0xC0DEDBAD
s = struct.pack(">L", i)  # ">" = Big-endian, "<" = Little-endian

import array
a = array.array("B")  # B: Unsigned bytes
a.fromstring(s)
print a   # array('B', [192, 222, 219, 173])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
exitstatus, signum= divmod(status, 256)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can unpack the status using [bit-shifting](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#shifting-operations) and [masking](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations) operators.

```
low = status & 0x00FF
high = (status & 0xFF00) >> 8
```

I'm not a Python programmer, so I hope got the syntax correct.

Answer (score 0):

The folks before me've nailed it, but if you really want it on one line, you can do this:

```
(signum, exitstatus) = (status & 0xFF, (status >> 8) & 0xFF)
```

EDIT: Had it backwards.

Answer (score 0):

```
import amp as amp
import status
signum = status &amp; 0xff
exitstatus = (status &amp; 0xff00) &gt;&gt; 8
```

Comment: This isn't much more useful than the existing answers. Perhaps you could try answering the new questions with no answers?

Comment: No problem. Your best is what this community would be honoured to have :)